# codeblocks createProcess no such file or directory error

Tags: c, codeblocks, createprocess

So I am very new to programming in C and i'm trying to install Code::Blocks. I downloaded the mingw setup and everything seemed to install correctly. However, when I try building the hello world program it gives me the error "CreateProcess no such file or directory". I have never worked with codeblocks or c before and quite frankly i have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [MinGW installation - Code::Blocks Configuration](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/MinGW_installation#Code::Blocks_Configuration)

Comment: thank you! I found out what was wrong and its working now

Comment: Could you tell us what was wrong?

Comment: the compiler's installation directory was wrong